# How to remove certain rows from pandas data frame if the counts of it is small

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove some data from pandas data frame. I have a data frames look like this:

```
sex     age         race                c_charge_desc
Male    0.204082    Hispanic            Felony Battery (Dom Strang)
Male    0.122449    African-American    Felony Driving While Lic Suspend
Female  0.163265    African-American    Neglect Child / No Bodily Harm
Male    0.081633    African-American    arrest case no charge
Male    0.530612    African-American    Felony Driving While Lic Suspend
```

There is a column named c_charge_desc that contains many different charge descriptions. I want to remove some charge descriptions which have a total number less than a threashold.

```
Battery                            924
arrest case no charge              904
Possession of Cocaine              378
Grand Theft in the 3rd Degree      352
Driving While License Revoked      158
                                  ... 
Compulsory Attendance Violation      1
Possession Of Clonazepam             1
Possession Of Anabolic Steroid       1
Attempt Burglary (Struct)            1
Fail To Redeliver Hire Prop          1
Name: c_charge_desc, Length: 387, dtype: int64
```

This is the summary of this column, you can see there are many descriptions which have a number of 1. I want to remove those descriptions with the total number of occurrence less than 10.

I have tried

```
df[df['c_charge_desc'].value_counts() < 10]
```

but this doesn't work, and I am getting this error

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

This will be my expected output

```
Battery                            924
arrest case no charge              904
Possession of Cocaine              378
Grand Theft in the 3rd Degree      352
Driving While License Revoked      158
...
Some charges                        10
Some charges                        10
Some charges                        10
Some charges                        10
Name: c_charge_desc, Length: 200, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Show your expected output.

Comment: ^comment above for sure, but I think you'd be better off splitting the charge description column into two separate columns and masking your dataframe with the numeric column.

Comment: @luthervespers Yeah, I will do that, but I need to eliminate those that have too few counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`groupby-filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) is probably most concise. For example, to keep only charges that occur more than once:

```py
df.groupby('c_charge_desc').filter(lambda group: len(group) > 1)

#     sex       age              race                     c_charge_desc
# 1  Male  0.122449  African-American  Felony Driving While Lic Suspend
# 4  Male  0.530612  African-American  Felony Driving While Lic Suspend
```

---

Alternatively, create a temporary `counter` column to use as a filter:

```py
df['counter'] = df.groupby('c_charge_desc').c_charge_desc.transform('count')
df[df.counter > 1].drop('counter', axis=1)
```